# Defining the Hirota operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction

The Hirota $D$-operator (derivative) is mathematically defined as follows:

$$D_x^n f\cdot g=\left.\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s ^n} f(x+s)g(x-s)\right|_{s=0} $$

An example of this operator acting on two functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ is the following:

$$D_x a(x)\cdot b(x) = a'(x)b(x)-a(x)b'(x)$$

I'm trying to make a Hirota $D$-operator function in *Mathematica*. What I've tried is the following

```
HirotaD[a[x_], b[x_], n_] :=
  Module[{},
   sol = D[a[x + y]*b[x - y], {y, n}] /. y -> 0 //

     TraditionalForm;
   Print[("\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(x\)]\)")^n, "=", sol]
   ];
```

This appears to work at first when I simply use arbitrary functions `a[x]` and `b[z]` as input functions:

```
HirotaD[a[x], b[x], 1]
(* ==> Subscript[D, x]=b(x)a'(x)-a(x) b'(x)  *)
```

**However, it fails to output anything when I use any predefined functions.**

```
f[x_]:=Sin[x];
g[x_]:=Cos[x];

HirotaD[f[x],g[x],1]
(* ==> HirotaD[Sin[x], Cos[x], 1] *)
```

**How do I make it work on predefined functions?**

Comment: Your definition only accepts the functions `a` and `b`, literally, with any argument, called `x`. Try `a_[x_]` etc. on the LHS of the definition.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer That was it!

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Hold on though, when I change it to `a_[x_]` it works with some simple predefined functions, but not with any functions which involve multiplication in it (weird...). For example, `f[x_]=a[x]*b[x]` doesn't work as a valid input function.

Comment: It's not weird: the pattern `a_[x_]` cannot possibly match `a[x]*b[x]`, can it? It seems the two arguments should be general **expressions**, i.e. just `a_`, `b_`, see @Lucas's answer.

Comment: If you do `SetAttributes[HirotaD, HoldAll]`, then define your function with `a_[x_]` and `b_[x_]` as suggested by @MariusLadegårdMeyer , it should work the way you're expecting.

Comment: Where does this operator operate, actually? (Domain) On pairs of functions like $(f(x),g(x))$? And if so, it must also produce pairs of functions (Range). Then at some point it seems one needs to map the pairs into products. But I don't think D itself can operate on functions of x directly, because $f(x)g(x) = g(x)f(x)$. So am I completely out of it or what? It seems like this needs to be straight in order that D with n=2 can agree with D applied twice, for example. Otherwise what's to keep me from writing $f'(x)g(x)$ as $g(x)f'(x)$ for instance at any step along the way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following definition takes as arguments two pure functions, `a` and `b`, their argument `x` and the parameter `n`.

```
HirotaD[a_, b_, x_, n_] := 
  Module[{}, 
   sol = D[a[x + y]*b[x - y], {y, n}] /. y -> 0 // TraditionalForm;
   Print[("\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(D\), \(x\)]\)")^n, "=", sol]];
```

It works on general functions, not yet defined.

```
HirotaD[a, b, x, 1]
(* Subscript[D, x]=b(x) a'(x)-a(x) b'(x) *)
```

On built in functions, like `Sin` and `Cos`

```
HirotaD[Sin, Cos, x, 1]
(* Subscript[D, x]=sin^2(x)+cos^2(x) *)
```

And on products of functions, but for more complicated uses, one has to define a pure function, as follows:

```
HirotaD[a[#] b[#] &, u, x, 1]
(* Subscript[D, x]=b(x) u(x) a'(x)+a(x) u(x) b'(x)-a(x) b(x) u'(x) *)
```

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd offer a definition that works more like Mathematica's `D` function:

```
HirotaD[a_, b_, x_, n_] := Module[{fa, fb, d, s}, (
   fa = a /. (x -> (x + s));
   fb = b /. (x -> (x - s));
   d = D[fa fb, {s, n}];
   d /. s -> 0 // Simplify
   )]

HirotaD[a_, b_, x_] := HirotaD[a, b, x, 1]
```

Which you can call like

```
HirotaD[a[x], b[x], x] (* General Example *)
HirotaD[Sin[x], Cos[x], x] (* Should give 1 *)
HirotaD[Sin[y], Cos[y], x] (* df[y]/dx = 0, should give 0 *)
HirotaD[a[x], b[x], x, 2] (* Second order *)
```

which gives

$b(x) a'(x) - a(x) b'(x)$

$0$

$1$

$b(x) a''(x)-2 a'(x) b'(x)+a(x) b''(x)$

Comment: Using the product rule: `HirotaD[a_, b_, x_, n_:1] := Sum[(-1)^(n - k) Binomial[n, k] Derivative[k][Function[x, a]][x] Derivative[n - k][Function[x, b]][x], {k, 0, n}]`

Comment: @J.M. Yup, kind of obvious when you see the form of the higher order derivatives.